# Make a map / array from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following object structure,

```
    {
        carMaker: {
            Id: '01',
            Name: 'Audi',
            Headquarter: 'Germany'
        },
        modelName: 'R8',
        Id: '1',
        CarMaker: 'Audi',
        color: 'black'
    }
```

Basically, this is a list of cars which references its CarMaker by name.
And the details of the CarMaker is also nested inside the json having key CarMaker.

What I want is to populate a JSON structure having list of CarMaker with the cars created by them in an array under key carsList.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to do this, without using two for loops which would be the easy way out and would affect the performance for larger values.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="../content/vendor_js/AngularJS/angular.js"></script>
        <script>

            var testmodule = angular.module('testmodule', []);

            testmodule.controller('testcontroller', ['$scope', function         ($scope) {
                $scope.carList = [
                    {
                        carMaker: {
                            Id: '01',
                            Name: 'Audi',
                            Headquarter: 'Germany'
                        },
                        modelName: 'R8',
                        Id: '1',
                        CarMaker: 'Audi',
                        color: 'black'
                    }, {
                        carMaker: {
                            Id: '01',
                            Name: 'Audi',
                            Headquarter: 'Germany'
                        },
                        modelName: 'A7',
                        Id: '2',
                        CarMaker: 'Audi',
                        color: 'red'
                    }, {
                        carMaker: {
                            Id: '02',
                            Name: 'Nissan',
                            Headquarter: 'Japan'
                        },
                        modelName: 'GTR',
                        Id: '4',
                        CarMaker: 'Nissan',
                        color: 'yellow'
                    }, {
                        carMaker: {
                            Id: '03',
                            Name: 'Volkswagen',
                            Headquarter: 'Germany'
                        },
                        modelName: 'Polo',
                        Id: '5',
                        CarMaker: 'Volkswagen',
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                ];

                $scope.carMakerList = {};
                $scope.createJSONArray = function () {
                    angular.forEach($scope.carList, function (car) {
                        $scope.carMakerList[car.carMaker.Name] =         car.carMaker;
                    });

                    angular.forEach($scope.carMakerList, function (carMaker)         {
                        carMaker.cars = [];
                    });

                    angular.forEach($scope.carList, function (car) {
                        $scope.carMakerList[car.CarMaker]["cars"].push(car);
                    });
                };

                $scope.createJSONArray();

            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="testmodule" ng-controller="testcontroller">
        <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="carmaker in carMakerList">
                <td><p ng-bind="carmaker.Id"></p></td>
                <td><p ng-bind="carmaker.Name"></p></td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="cars in carmaker.cars">
                            <p ng-bind="cars.modelName"></p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <h3></h3>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please add the wanted structure and the code you tried.

Comment: You haven't shown any effort in trying to solve this yourself.

Comment: please make a valid object structure with only one property `CarMaker`.

Comment: Sorry to have not provided the exact structure, I have updated the question with proper code. Apologize for not making a fiddle because I do not know how to add angular.js file to the fiddle. I have written down my whole code in the question above now. @Nina Scholz

Comment: *would affect the performance for larger values* Actually, it wouldn't, probably, and certainly is not worth worrying about until you've established that it is.

Answer (score 2):

This is a single loop proposal with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object as reference to `carsList`.

```js
var data = [{ carMaker: { Id: '01', Name: 'Audi', Headquarter: 'Germany' }, modelName: 'R8', Id: '1', CarMaker: 'Audi', color: 'black' }, { carMaker: { Id: '01', Name: 'Audi', Headquarter: 'Germany' }, modelName: 'A7', Id: '2', CarMaker: 'Audi', color: 'red' }, { carMaker: { Id: '02', Name: 'Nissan', Headquarter: 'Japan' }, modelName: 'GTR', Id: '4', CarMaker: 'Nissan', color: 'yellow' }, { carMaker: { Id: '03', Name: 'Volkswagen', Headquarter: 'Germany' }, modelName: 'Polo', Id: '5', CarMaker: 'Volkswagen', color: 'black' }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = a.carMaker.Name, o;
    if (!this[key]) {
        o = { Id: a.carMaker.Id, Name: a.carMaker.Name, Headquarter: a.carMaker.Headquarter, carsList: [] };
        this[key] = o.carsList;
        grouped.push(o);
    }
    this[key].push({ modelName: a.modelName, Id: a.Id, color: a.color });        
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation Nina, +1 for that, but the approach of creating a new object altogether is a bit tedious if I have many keys, not just the limited Id, Name, Headquarter. But the approach is good for now, learnt a few things from you :)

Comment: for many keys, you could use an array with the keys and interate over for creating all new properties.